# In Haxe how do you implement array operators for a class?

Tags: haxe

I am trying to write a class in Haxe supporting array like access using the `[]` operator such as:

```
var vector = new Vec3();
trace(vector.length); // displays 3
vector[0] = 1; // array like access to the class, how?
vector[1] = 5.6; // more array access
vector[2] = Math.PI; // yet more array access
```

The problem is I don't know how to define a class such that it allows the `[]` operator. I need this class, rather than using an `Array<Float>` or `List<Float>` because there is some trickery going on with it to support my animation system which references to parts of vectors using storyboards (see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijF50rRbRZI)

In C# i could write:

```
public float this[index] { get { ... } set { .... } }
```

I've read the Haxe documentation and found `ArrayAccess<T>`, but the interface is empty. That is I don't understand how to *implement* it, or if I just implement `ArrayAccess<Float>` ... what method on my class would be called to retrieve `Float` at said *index*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haxe doesn't support operators overload (yet) so you will have to use a get/set pair. You can use inline if the magic that happens inside your methods need to be optimized for speed.